# Password validation message is not displaying for alphanumeric regex format

Tags: regex, reactjs, passwords, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Password validation message is not triggering, even if I provide just letters or just numbers in password field. 
My intention is that, the password field should trigger validation message if the password is not `alphanumeric` format. I am using `react-hook-form`

```
<label>
<input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"
                onChange={onChange}
                minLength={6}
                ref={register({
                  required: "Required",
                  pattern: {
                    value: /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/,
                    message: "Password should include letter and numbers !"
                  }
                })}
 />
<span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.password && errors.password.message}</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your reg expression allows either digits or letters, not at least one of each. change it to -

```
/^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]+$/
```

first `(?=.*?\d)` at least one `d`igit, second `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` for at least one `a-zA-Z` (capital or not), and finally `[a-zA-Z\d]+` as you wrote for only those types